# How do you use keywords in a link to a page without making the page containing the link start to rank for those keywords?

Tags: seo, links, keywords, anchor-text

How do I write a good descriptive link, without ranking the linking page for the same keywords of the same article?

Comment: So basically you want to create multiple links pointing to a same page?

Comment: Depends. I have an article, it is related to another article. I want to create a link like :"look also". Basically the A link to B. The link to B should not contain keywords for which B ranks for. (If that makes sense at all' of course).  But "look also" is a boring sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try and understand your issue.

You have a page, lets call A: `www.example.com/blue-widgets/` and you have another page, lets call it B: `www.example.com/red-widgets/`

You want to link from A to B using anchor text which is relevent to B, but you are afraid if you use words that are relevant to page B, page A will start to rank for them.

You don't need to worry about this, simply using a few words won't change what the page is relevant for (unless there is no other content on the page?), and just adding a few words wont make it rank for those words.

So you can safely link from `www.example.com/blue-widgets/` to `www.example.com/red-widgets/` using an anchor such as `Check out our red widgets page`